# Where do I move my String?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

I have to move String[] du = new String[ruu];, currently under if(dru == 1). The issue is where, and how to make it so that the rest of the code follows it. How would I approach this? This is what I have:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean hah = true;
        Scanner dea = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.println("1. Create League.");
            System.out.println("2. Look up Teams.");
            System.out.println("3. Mark Win.");
            System.out.println("4. Mark Loss.");
            System.out.println("5. Quit.");
            int dru = dea.nextInt();

            if (dru == 1) {
                System.out.println("How many Teams?");
                int ruu = dea.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Fine. Just give a name.");
                dea.nextLine();
                String[] du = new String[ruu];

                for (int i = 0; i < du.length; i++) {
                    if (i >= 1)
                        System.out.println("More are required.");
                    du[i] = (String) (dea.nextLine());
                }
                System.out.println("Teams: " + Arrays.toString(du));
                if (dru == 5 && hah == true)
                    System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                hah = false;
                if (hah == false)
                    break;
            }
        } while (hah == true);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's happening currently when you run it?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation as it's impossible to tell which levels of indentation some of your code is in (which is vital because it could be breaking your program).

Comment: The indentation is fixed. When I run it, I go to the menu and my options show up. When i go for if(dru ==1), it works up until the teams are listed. It terminates right after, when it should do that on if(dru ==5 && hah == true). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several Problems.

The `hah = false;` line should be indented under the `if(dru == 5 && hah == true)` line.

You're asking the program to set `hah` to `false` (and essentially terminate the program) `if(dru == 5 && hah == true)`. Problem is, you're doing this inside the `if (dru == 1)` section, so `dru` can never be `5` unless you reassign `dru`. Also, this means that `Goodbye` won't be printed as `dru` can never be `5`, so your program will terminate, but not print `Goodbye`.

Next problem, you're not asking the user if they want to quit, therefore not giving them a chance to enter `5`, so that `dru = 5`, meaning that your program won't terminate (after you've fixed the aforementioned indentation problem).